# Send back acknowledgement from Axis2 handler without dropping original message

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I have a scenario where an acknowledgement should be sent to the requestor that the message was successfully validated and accepted, however the original message should continue it's normal flow execution.

My module consists of a simple handler that performs some validation stuff and should send an acknowledgement to the requestor:

```
public class ValidationHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    //Validation logic goes here
    return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
}
```

How I could send the acknowledgement from the handler not breaking the initial message flow?

Thanks,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ;

```
AxisEngine.send(arg0);
```

in your handler to send a response back to client..

Here is a [sample post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/11/send-back-custom-response-in.html), which talks about sending error message..You can refer that to send a custom response..

Comment: This is the exact thing I was using, however I'm getting:    java.lang.NullPointerException in AxisEngine.java:419 which stands for OperationContext operationContext = msgContext.getOperationContext();

Comment: Ha..You have to set some parameters in the messagecontext...Since it is, you're trying to send back that to client, i believe you have to set "To" address, such parameters..Because the original messagecontext will have the parameters related to your actual endpoint..You can debug and set those parameters..

Comment: I'm using the following to build out context: MessageContext outMsgContext = MessageContextBuilder.createOutMessageContext(messageContext); AxisEngine.send(outMsgContext);

Comment: The problem was that I had to move my own phase to be executed after dispatch phase, however I'm getting the following exceptio now:

Comment: [2014-01-22 18:25:13,833] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSender.determineHttpSta
tusCode(HttpCoreNIOSender.java:687)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSender.sendAsyncRespons
e(HttpCoreNIOSender.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSender.invoke(HttpCoreN
IOSender.java:315)

Comment: @VladimirKlevko So, now axis handler issue sorted out? Now why you get above NHTTP transport error?

Comment: I have no idea of this exception. I'm doing the following: MessageContext outMsgContext = MessageContextBuilder.createOutMessageContext(inMsgContext); outMsgContext.setEnvelope(buildResponseEnvelope()); AxisEngine.send(outMsgContext); and get these exceptions.

Comment: Since it is wso2 implementation it was hard to determine he root cause of the problem. Now solved and this approach works well. Solved.

Comment: What is the solution now you used?..Actually, it was not clear where the error comes..Because, initially you said, there is an issue in axis2 handler..later some issue at transport level..